# express request Error: socket hangup while parsing large xml

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, express

Im trying to parse a 300MB xml file into json in a worker nodejs app, so the client makes the request to the main web app and the server performs request to the worker server with the file location, after the worker server finished parsing the xml it saves it to a json file and return its location back to the main server.

Everything works fine with xml files under 130MB, however when it encounters a large file the worker server finished parsing the file and saves it, as soon as the response comes to the main server it receives :

```
 { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

I have tried to use timeout in the request options, but it still happening.

```
request
      .post({
             url:'http://localhost:6666/parsexml',
             formData: {filePath:filePath},
             json: true
      },function(err,httpResponse,jsonResObj){
         // throws error here
      })
```

- the xml parser worker return 200 message back to the server, and then it crashes.

Anny suggestion on how can i implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use different XML parser, for example [xml-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xml-stream), which can handle large (500+ MB) files.

**How can you install it**

Install it using the following command:
`npm install -g xml-stream`

**How you can use it in your app**

Require it in your project and pass the `ReadFile` object to initialize it:

```
var fs        = require('fs');
var XmlStream = require('xml-stream');
/*
   * Pass the ReadStream object to xml-stream
*/
var stream=fs.createReadStream('file_name.xml');
var xml = new XmlStream(stream);
/*
  *Code continues here
*/
```

If you want to extract only values of, let's say, `id` from your XML and print them this is a code to do so:

```
var fs        = require('fs')
var XmlStream = require('xml-stream') ;
var stream=fs.createReadStream('some-large-XML.xml');
var xml = new XmlStream(stream);
xml.preserve('id', true);
xml.collect('subitem');
xml.on('endElement: id', function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

More detailed information can be found [here](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/10/parse-large-xml-files-node/).

Comment: Thank you for the response, Im needed to create a complete xml-to-json convsersion with no need in any attributes or other special functionalities.

Comment: I mcurrently using : https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js and it really works fine, with only this issue... (im not even sure its the parser fault, since it creates the json perfectly)